Why can't I set a variable and then echo it right away in bash
EDIT: The point of this question is to make it possible to Google this.  While the flagged duplicate question has the same answer, it's in some sense not the same question, because that question is specifically about using env.

In bash, why does
A=1 echo $A

produce a blank line instead of
1

as expected?

Because variable expansion is done before executing line. At time $A is empty. Search for variable expansion in bash's man page!

You would only expect 1 if you don't understand 1) What a precommend assignment (not a previous assignment statement) is and 2) how environment variables are used.

Answer:
Bash evaluates $A prior to running A=1.
Demonstration:
$ export A=1
$ A=2 echo $A
1

One workaround:
$ cat > echoa.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $A
^D
$ chmod +x echoa.sh
$ A=5 ./echoa.sh
5


or A=1 bash -c 'echo $A'
